# SPFx - Application Customizer for SharePoint Online Deployment results into DOM Exception Error

Tags: reactjs, github, sharepoint-online, spfx

DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.

I am facing one issue after deploying the SPFx solution which is used to display a custom header as an application customizer, whenever I minimize the browser or move the page from one screen to another (Laptop to Monitor) it is set to white background with an error in console Log1.

ReactDOM.render(elem, headerData.domElement); // Issue occurs on this line of statement.

[Console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSXmC.png)

When I am viewing the SharePoint list it's resulting in the same error.
[SharePoint List View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgunR.png)